# Replace 'enter' with <Br> tags in a php-posting script

Tags: php, post, replace

I'm aware that there are multiple examples of this within this forum and others, I've tried them all, but couldn't get either to work.
I got a php-script that writes to a php-file, wich gets loaded within a php script.

My purpose is to get automatic br-tags into the php-post once people push 'enter'

```
<?php
        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
        $com  = $_POST['txt'];
        If ($com === "") {
        echo "<font color=red><b>You must write something to post!</font></b>";
        die;
        }
        $time = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s",time()+(2*60*60));
        $com  = $_POST['txt'];
        $count = strlen($com);
        $com = stripslashes($com);
        $breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");
        $com = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $com);
        $fp = $file = fopen( "NAME_OF_POST.php", "a");
        Multiple fwrites follows.....
        Multiple fwrites follows.....
        rewind($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>';
        }
        ?>
```

and it loads within:

```
<textarea name="txt" id="area" class="typo_vind" placeholder="......" tabindex="1"></textarea>
```

Anyone knows how to get linebreaks from enter to be replaced with br-tags?

In advance, than you :)!

Comment: Use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) and don't use the `<font>`-element nowadays.

Comment: Have you tried $your_string = str_replace("\r\n", "<br/>", $your_string);

Comment: Oh, damn, the prew comment that stated the fact that i've been writing backwards solved my problem :)

Comment: Thank you guys, once I noticed it worked out, thanks :)!

Comment: thank you for the comment referring to nl2br, looks like I got quite some rescripting-work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $breaks = array("\n");
        $com = str_ireplace($breaks, "<br />", $com);
```

Switching places did the trick :) Thank you all:)

Answer (score 3):

Well, php has a function for that:

```
$yourString = "text
               with
               enters";
$result = nl2br( $yourString );
print $result

// output:
// text<br>with<br>enters
```

look at [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 0):

OMG !!!!!!!

```
$breaks = array("\n");
$com = str_ireplace($breaks, "<br />", $com);
```

After a lot of search this work well !!!!!!!
♥☻☻☻♥♥♥

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer